# How to pass value from application.yaml to @FeignClient annotation?

Tags: java, spring, feign

How can I pass value from application.yaml:

```
feign:
  client:
    config:
      sampleclient:
      url: http://localhost:8083
```

to @FeignClient annotation:

```
@FeignClient(value="sampleclient", url="${feign.client.config.sampleclient.url}")
```

?

Comment: Please edit your question. It's not clear

Comment: For some reason yaml properties files are not working with feign correctly. Try with application.properties (feign.client.config.sampleclient.url) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: you can't. Annotations arguments must be compile-time constants. Variables from `application.yml` are not.